# Ubuntu kernel can't read its own root partition, but LiveCDs can?

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, grubrescue, fsck

My `/` partition is unreadable from the hard drive install, but I just ran `fsck` on it and know it's clean.  I can open it in Nautilus from the LiveCD but `chroot`ing to it doesn't work!  It [the `chroot`ed install] gives me errors when I try to run `dpkg` or `apt-get`.  What's going on?  Why can't Ubuntu start if the partition is fine?  I re-installed GRUB using `boot-repair` ([sourceforge site](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/)) and now it doesn't drop me to rescue prompt, but when I start Ubuntu it loads the kernel and initial ramdisk but can't seem to access its own disk.   Is there any command line wizardry I can run from the rescue prompt?  What's going on?

**More information:**

Recovery Mode results:

Trying to run chkdsk results in an error: `Mountall: Disconnected from Upstart`

Trying to drop to root shell results in an error: `sulogin: cannot open user password database`

"System Config" results are fine but it tells me under APT that "`Database is consistent: no (BAD)`".  This is worrying.

The root partition is reported as having 0.05% noncontiguous space, so there are no fragmentation problems.

Something possibly unrelated is in the wall of text that appears whenever you boot without `quiet splash`, I saw something along the lines of "sdhci-pci 0:00:02 **invalid iomem size - you may experience problems**.  (I don't know what this is, but it scares me!)

I ran `boot-repair` twice; once to get GRUB working and not drop me to rescue prompt and another time to try to purge and re-install grub.  It wanted me to `chroot` to my old install and then run `dpkg-reconfigure` to uninstall and reinstall GRUB, but upon trying to run the uninstall command it told me that the command was not installed (will post screens when I find the flash drive I saw them on).

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1389119/)'s my current bootinfo (generated by boot-repair).  `sdc` is a flash drive that I had plugged in (and subsequently lost -_-), I didn't know it would be picked up by the script.  [This](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1389003/) is a bootconfig summary from an hour earlier.

(I'll post screenshots when I get my flash drive.)

Comment: You should post the errors you are getting. Without them it is difficult to guess what is really happening. Tip: use `pastebinit` or paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: I got all of those (errors) already on paste.ubuntu.com and screenshots besides, but I just want to know if there are any general things I might be missing.

Comment: will post all information in a couple hours when i get back

Comment: I would guess this is a problem with GRUB (maybe the partition specified in the boot entry is wrong, or the UUID of it). So if you can, check the content of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and see if everything is right.

Comment: Grub starts up fine and the initramfs and kernel is loaded, so the UUID is right.  I can start recovery mode and all, but it's just the *already loaded linux* that can't see its own partition.

Comment: You say your system can't access the disk after loading the kernel. Don't you get any error there (like can't mount device) or are dropped to busybox?

Comment: "general mount error" but it reboots too quickly to see any error message after that.  Thank you for your help, but I've done something to fix it (see that post I'm about to make)

Comment: (I have to wait 23h to accept my answer, but thank you very much for your interest.) (Have a "helpful comment"!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm going to mark this (what I did) as the answer, although if someone comes along with a detailed guide of how to diagnose early-stage kernel problems they will certainly get accepted answer and an upvote!

In 12.10, there is a (apparently at least) new feature.  When Ubiquity detects 12.10 (and/or another install, but not more than 3 OSes in total including 12.10) it gives three options: "Reinstall 12.10" (keeps documents and settings and tries to keep programs), "Replace/Erase 12.10" (not actual title text) (wipes your 12.10 partition), and "Erase everything (new partition table, etc.).  I tried the reinstall option and it *was* able to get a working Ubuntu install back again.  However, it broke my mouse support, so I did some partition copying and shrinking and a complete reinstall.

**TL:DR** Everything's fixed now, although I still don't know what caused the problem.